# How do I round the number in a textbox to 2 decimals in C#?

Tags: c#, parsing, integer, decimal

I have a price textbox and I want to get a decimal value with 2 decimals, no matter the original string is a already a decimal or an integer. For example:

```
input = 12 --> output = 12.00
input = 12.1 --> output = 12.10
input = 12.123 --> output = 12.12
```

Comment: Be aware that the accepted answer gives you a string that might not always be what you want.  For instance, `(12.125m).ToString("N")` is `"12.13"`, and `(12.135m).ToString("N")` is  `"12.14"` (`AwayFromZero` rounding).  But `Math.Round(12.125m, 2);` is `12.12` while `Math.Round(12.135m, 2);` is `12.14`.  Be careful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this method `decimal.ToString("N");`

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `.ToString()` overload that takes a string as a format:

```
var roundedInput = input.ToString("0.00");
```

Of course, this results in a string type.

To simply round, you can use `Math.Round`:

```
var roundedInput = Math.Round(input, 2);
```

You should be aware that by default, `Math.Round` uses "banker's rounding" method, which you might not want.  In which case, you might need to use the overload that takes the rounding type enum:

```
var roundedInput = Math.Round(input, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```

See the method overload documentation that uses `MidpointRounding` here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131275.aspx

Also be aware that the default rounding method for `Math.Round` is different than the default rounding method used in `decimal.ToString()`.  For instance:

```
(12.125m).ToString("N");  // "12.13"
(12.135m).ToString("N");  // "12.14"
Math.Round(12.125m, 2);   // 12.12
Math.Round(12.135m, 2);   // 12.14
```

Depending on what your situation is, using the wrong techniques could be very bad!!

Answer (score 3):

```
// just two decimal places
String.Format("{0:0.00}", 123.4567);      // "123.46"
String.Format("{0:0.00}", 123.4);         // "123.40"
String.Format("{0:0.00}", 123.0);         // "123.00"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Input.Text = Math.Round(z, # Places).ToString();
```

Comment: this returns the rounded answer, but does not complete the formatting as requested